# How to combine multiple arrays within element of list in Python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a question concerning the combination of several arrays to one array. I have a list of length 1000 and in each element of the list there are 16 arrays of dimension 100, what I want to achieve is a list of 1000 elements and each element has a array of dimension 1600.  How can I achieve this: I tried the following: `x=np.concetate(x, axis=0)` which returns dimensions of 16'000 x 100 and `x=np.concetate(x, axis=1)` which returns dimensions of 16 x 100'000. I also tried `x=np.vstack` and `x=np.hstack`, but I was not able to get it myself. Could somebody help me?

Thanks!

Edit: Minimal working sample:

I have something like this, first in a dataframe

```
Date    | Company A     | Company B     | Company C ...  
1.01.16 | [1, 2, 3 ...] | [4, 5, 6 ...] | [7, 8, 9 ...]
...
```

Then I converted it to a list using `df.values.tolist()` and now I would like to have something like that:

```
[1,2,3,...,4,5,6,...,7,8,9...]
```

for each row in the dataframe.

Comment: I think you can do `np.reshape(x,(1000,1600))`. If you post a minimal working example it would make it easier for users to help you. For instance, you haven't stated anything about the order of the elements in the lists etc.

Comment: @tch I tried to add a minimal working example to make it clear.

Comment: And I realized it worked with your approach, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the question is really asking is about reshaping a numpy array. You simply have to use the numpy method `reshape`. Reshape takes an existing numpy array and the 2 new dimentions then copies the result to a new object. For example, in your specific case

`a = np.reshape(x,(1000,1600))`